# Only one of my enemy's are shooting bullets pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have been trying to make it so when my enemy.x is < 700 then it start's shooting at the player, but it is not working for me, It is only working for one of them and the one it is only working for is one of the enemy's called enemy1.  I have tried using the same code I have used for the player but that did not work, also I have looked at the errors but there is none, also I have checked my indention.

https://gyazo.com/88e7499705f715082e1398bff0c3c91b

My enemy1 is shooting but my other enemys are not

this is were my problem is at

```
# This is enemy bullets and when player press Spacebar they come
    for egun in eguns:
        if egun.x < 700 and egun.x > 0:
            egun.x -= egun.speed 
        else:
            eguns.pop(eguns.index(egun))
    for enemy in enemys:
        if enemy.x < 700 and etimer == 0:
            if len(eguns) < 30:
                eguns.append(enemybullets(round(enemy.x+enemy.width//2),round(enemy.y + enemy.height-24),(0,0,0)))

            etimer = 1
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Build The Screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))

# Name Screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")

bg = pygame.image.load("skybg1.png")
bg_shift = 0


# Class Player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 6
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("heroplane1.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        player_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        player_rect.centerx += -7
        player_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,player_rect)

# Class Enemy
class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 4
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("enemyplane1.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        enemy_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy_rect.centerx += -2
        enemy_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy_rect)


# Class Enemy2
class enemy2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("enemyplane2.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        enemy2_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy2_rect.centerx += -4
        enemy2_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy2_rect)


# Class Enemy3
class enemy3:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("enemyplane3.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        enemy3_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy3_rect.centerx += -4
        enemy3_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy3_rect)



class projectile(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("herogun1.png")
       self.slash = pygame.transform.scale(self.slash,(self.slash.get_width()//11,self.slash.get_height()//11))
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(self.slash, self.rect)

class enemybullets(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("enemygun1.png")
       self.slash = pygame.transform.scale(self.slash,(self.slash.get_width()//11,self.slash.get_height()//11))
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(self.slash, self.rect)



        
# Color
white = (255,255,255)

# Draw Player
playerman = player(5,250,90,40,white)

# For Enemy
enemy1 = enemy(400,100,90,40,white)
enemy4 = enemy(400,400,90,40,white)

# For Enemy2
enemy21 = enemy2(400,300,90,40,white)

# For Enemy3
ememy31 = enemy3(400,400,90,40,white)


enemys = [enemy1,enemy4]


# enemys
enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
level1 = [
"                        1         1            1                                                           ",
"                             1         1       1      1          1      1    1    1    1    1     1                            ",
"                          1                 1               1      1                 1                  1   ",
"                   1          1         1      1    1    1        1   1    1    1         1     1                ",
"                    1    1         1           1         1    1                      1   1    1     1     1    1  ",
"                              1           1                             1     1                                    ",
"                      1   1       1   1       1    1     1     1    1              1     1      1      1       ",]


for iy, row in enumerate(level1):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_enemy = enemy(ix*70,iy*70,90,40,(255,255,255))
            enemys.append(new_enemy)



# Redrawwinodw
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    bg_width = bg.get_width()
    bg_offset = bg_shift % bg_width 
    
    window.blit(bg, (-bg_offset, 0)) 
    window.blit(bg, (bg_width - bg_offset, 0))

    
    # Draw playerman
    playerman.draw()

    # Draw enemy
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.draw()

    # Draw enemy2
    enemy21.draw()

    # Draw enemy3
    ememy31.draw()


    # Draw enemygun

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)

    for egun in eguns:
        egun.draw(window)





# FPS Cnd Clock
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# For Bullets List And Timer
bullets = []

btimer = 0

# For Enemy Bullets And Timer
eguns = []

etimer = 0

# Main Loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # Timer for Bullets
    if btimer > 0:
        btimer += 1
    if btimer > 10:
        btimer = 0

    # Timer for Enemy Bullets
    if etimer > 0:
        etimer += 1
    if etimer > 13:
        etimer = 0

# This Is Keys for bullet
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # This is bullets and when player press Spacebar they come
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 700 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.speed 
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and btimer == 0:
        if len(bullets) < 5:
                bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2),round(playerman.y + playerman.height-24),(0,0,0)))

        btimer = 1




    # This is enemy bullets and when player press Spacebar they come
    for egun in eguns:
        if egun.x < 700 and egun.x > 0:
            egun.x -= egun.speed 
        else:
            eguns.pop(eguns.index(egun))
    for enemy in enemys:
        if enemy.x < 700 and etimer == 0:
            if len(eguns) < 30:
                eguns.append(enemybullets(round(enemy.x+enemy.width//2),round(enemy.y + enemy.height-24),(0,0,0)))

            etimer = 1



    # For enemy to Move
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.x -= enemy.speed
    


    bg_shift += round(3/2)


    # Keys For Playerman
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
       
        

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and playerman.x < 260 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_w] and playerman.y > playerman.speed:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_s] and playerman.y < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        playerman.y += playerman.speed


            
# Update And Other Sutff    
    redrawwindow()


    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Not positive but I am guessing it has to do with the [event queue.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121244/pygame-when-i-release-two-directional-keys-together-the-player-keep-moving)

Comment: Not sure if this has any impact but you have a variable enemy and a class enemy. I would suggest renaming either to prevent any form of unintended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention (e.g. `class enemy` -> `class Enemy`).
It is completely sufficient to implement one single class `Enemy`. The image is an attribute of the class and the image filename can be an argument to the constructor.

Anyway, the major issue is, that you've just 1 global variable `btimer`. `btimer` has to be an attribute of the class `Enemy`:

```py
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color,imagefile):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 4
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//9,self.ss1.get_height()//9))

        self.etimer = 0 # <---

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
        enemy_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        enemy_rect.centerx += -2
        enemy_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(self.ss1,enemy_rect)
```

```py
# For Enemy
enemy1 = Enemy(400, 100, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane1.png")
enemy4 = Enemy(400, 400, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane1.png")

# For Enemy2
enemy21 = Enemy(400, 300, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane2.png")

# For Enemy3
ememy31 = Enemy(400, 400, 90, 40, white, "enemyplane3.png")
```

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    # Timer for Enemy Bullets
    for enemy in enemys:
        if enemy.etimer > 0:
            enemy.etimer += 1
        if enemy.etimer > 13:
            enemy.etimer = 0

    # [...]

    for enemy in enemys:
        if enemy.x < 700 and enemy.etimer == 0:
            if len(eguns) < 30:
                eguns.append(enemybullets(round(enemy.x+enemy.width//2),round(enemy.y + enemy.height-24),(0,0,0)))
            enemy.etimer = 1
```